# Self-Hosted Calendar WebUI for displaying Free/Busy Slots (CalDav)

Tags: web-apps, web-browser, calendar, self-hosted, webdav

Are there any open-source web applications that will take a user's CalDAV credentials and display a nice calendar in the browser, showing the user's free/busy calendar?

Our mail/calendar server supports making our user's free/busy calendars (that's their calendars with the event names, descriptions, and attendees obfuscated for privacy -- only the start & end time of the events is shown). So we can make the free/busy schedule publicly accessible on a CalDAV URL. But, unfortunately, our webmail doesn't have a way to display the free/busy schedule on a public URL without authentication.

I'm looking for just a simple web server that I can throw in a DMZ and configure it to display a calendar with our users's free/busy schedules (via CalDAV). The URL to the web server should not require a username/password to access, so I can just write it on a business card for people to find when I'm free to schedule a meeting.

Comment: I got a POC working that mostly met my needs, but it's not free and not self-hosted https://www.memotoo.com/

Comment: See also https://foss-notes.blog.nomagic.uk/2019/04/display-your-ics-calendar-on-your-website/